# Access Denied Error when calling REST Call for specific user

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, access-denied

I have created a script to fetch data from the list in SharePoint Online. To do so, there has been given a REST call to the list to fetch data. There is one user who is facing the issue that is shown in the screenshot.

[image]

`https://<<siteCollection>>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('FAQ')/items?$select=*,Function/Title,Region/Title&$expand=Function,Region`

The issue comes for the one user only. Other users who has permission on the site are able to see the records as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please double check the permission of this specific user.

Comment: User has been given Contribute permission on the list.

Comment: Well in this case there should not be any problem..It should work. Can you share your code ...

Comment: what the endpoint you are calling ? also, are your custom js files checked in ?

Comment: Modified question. @GautamSheth

Comment: I see that you are using a lookup columns, You also need to provide access to the "looked up" lists. The looked up lists could be Function and Region, so you need to give access to both lists

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, based on the REST query that you have posted, you are using lookup columns.

So, you need to provide access to the lookup lists (could be named `Function` and `Region`) as well besides the `FAQ` list.

For that particular user or a SharePoint group, you can provide the minimum `read permissions` so that you can fetch data from those lists as well.

Summary - Just provide the basic read permissions on the 3 lists namely FAQ, Function and Region and you are good to go.